# Failed to create Firebase Dynamic Link using react-native-firebase - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

Recently I have updated my React Native application to version 0.59.10 ... I am using a package [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) version 5.5.5 for integrating Firebase into my application ... I did update this package as well along with my RN app. I am programmatically creating dynamic links using the package mentioned above ... before the upgrade, the dynamic links were being created successfully but after the updated when I try to create a dynamic link I get this error.

```
Error: Failed to create Dynamic Link
    at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:155)
    at NativeModules.js:104
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:414)
    at MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
    at e (RNDebuggerWorker.js:1)
```

This is a long link creation using the below mentioned method as mentioned in react-native-firebase documentation.

```js
const link = 
  new firebase.links.DynamicLink('https://example.com?param1=foo&param2=bar', 'abc123.page.link')
    .android.setPackageName('com.example.android')
    .ios.setBundleId('com.example.ios');

firebase.links()
    .createDynamicLink(link)
    .then((url) => {
      // ...
    });
```

Please note this is only happening in iOS ... In Android, I can generate a long link successfully.

This is my JS implementation in RN Application.

```js
class Referral extends Component {
    state = {
        shareLink: ''
    };
    onShare = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await Share.share({
                message: 'Hey found this new great app for ordering ... You should try it as well.',
                url: this.state.shareLink
            });

            if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
                if (result.activityType) {
                    // shared with activity type of result.activityType
                } else {
                    // shared
                }
            } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
                // dismissed
            }
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Opps', error.message);
        }
    };

    onPressTermsCondition = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('TermsAndConditions');
    };

    generateShareLink = async () => {
        console.log('PRESSED');
        const identifier = 'com.example.myapp';
        const firebaseDynamicLinkPrefix = 'myapp.page.link';
        const deepLink = 'https://www.example.com/?referralCode=foo&referralType=bar';
        const shareLink = new firebase.links.DynamicLink(
            deepLink,
            firebaseDynamicLinkPrefix
        ).android
            .setPackageName(identifier)
            .ios.setBundleId(identifier);

        console.log('SHARE LINK', shareLink);

        firebase
            .links()
            .createDynamicLink(shareLink)
            .then(url => {
                // ...
                console.log('LINK', url);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('ERROR', e));

        // firebase
        //     .links()
        //     .createShortDynamicLink(shareLink, 'UNGUESSABLE')
        //     .then(url => {
        //         // ...
        //         console.log('URL', url);
        //         this.setState({ shareLink: url }, () => {
        //             //this.onShare();
        //             console.log('LINK SAVED');
        //         });
        //     })
        //     .catch(e => console.log('ERROR', e));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <View style={styles.heading}>
                        <Text style={styles.headingText}>Refer a friend</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.subHeading}>
                        <Text style={styles.subHeadingText}>Share the Eat&#39;n Love</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.content}>
                    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                        <Image source={friendsGroup} style={styles.image} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>
                            Get upto 10% discount when someone signs up using your referral code and
                            place their first order over $10. Your friend also gets $7 off.
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.sharingContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.sharingDescriptionContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.sharingDescriptionText}>Tap to share</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.shareButtonContainer}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={styles.shareButton}
                                onPress={() => this.generateShareLink()}
                            >
                                <View style={styles.shareIconContainer}>
                                    <Image source={shareIcon} style={styles.shareIcon} />
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.referralCodeContainer}>
                                    <Text style={styles.referralCodeText}>89sd8293</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.emptyView} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.termsContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.termsText} onPress={() => this.onPressTermsCondition()}>
                        Terms&nbsp;&#38;&nbsp;Conditions
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Referral;
```

This is my POD File.

```rb
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do

  #pod 'Stripe', '~> 11.2.0'

  #pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  #pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.3.0'

  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 6.3.0'

  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 6.3.0'

  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 6.3.0'
  
  #pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'

  #pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'

  #pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

  #pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  #pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This is my AppDelegate.m.

```c
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
#import "RNFirebaseLinks.h"


#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import "RNSplashScreen.h"  // react native splash screen link
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"com.example.myapp";
  [FIRApp configure];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [RNSplashScreen show];  // react native splash screen link

  return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{

  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]] || [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
  
   return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
@end
```

I have been trying to find the solution for this on the internet but haven't found any so I turned to the gurus here ... Please point me in the right direction. TIA

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
const firebaseDynamicLinkPrefix = 'myapp.page.link';
```

to

```
const firebaseDynamicLinkPrefix = 'https://myapp.page.link';
```